# JavaFX - SWT interop: application freezes

Tags: java, swt, javafx-2, eclipse-rcp

I am building a RCP application, based on Eclipse 3.5. Thanks to two articles ([1](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm), [2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD)) that I've found on oracle.com, I have been able to implement a working RCP view, that displays a pie chart.

Unfortunately, if I close the view and reopen it, then the applications freezes and never comes back.

I am using JavaFX 2.2.7, under JDK 1.6.0.31 on Windows 7 X64.

Here is the code. The view is a standard subclass of org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart.

```
    Composite panel = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    FXCanvas fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(panel, SWT.NONE) {
        @Override
        public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
            getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            int width = (int) getScene().getWidth();
            int height = (int) getScene().getHeight();
            return new Point(width, height);
        }
    };

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    RGB rgb = panel.getBackground().getRGB();
    Color color = Color.rgb(rgb.red, rgb.green, rgb.blue);
    scene.setFill(color);
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("label1", 20));
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("label2", 20));
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("label3", 20));
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("label4", 20));
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data("label5", 20));
    Chart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
    chart.setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);
    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);
    fxCanvas.setScene(scene);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are there no exceptions?

Comment: No, there are no exceptions, no thread dump, no logs, nothing: it just freezes.

Comment: Do you see stuck thread(s) if you do a thread dump (VisualVM)?

Comment: no stuck threads either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved. It was caused by some Thread naming tweaks somewhere else in the app. There are definitely things that one should not do. Overly relying on thread names is one of them. :)

A utility class was relying on thread names to run code in the UI thread and because JavaFX changes the name of the running thread, the utility class would not work correctly anymore.